# Video conferencing with 10+ participants for free?

Tags: gratis, video-conferencing

I wonder if mid-2014, with a massive rise of WebRTC, are there any free tools allowing video conferencing or just audio chat for 15/20/50/100 participants?

- **Skype:** http://www.skype.com/en/group-video-call/ *(up to 10)*
- **Google Hangouts:** https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/how-many-people-can-be-on-a-google-hangout *(up to 10, up to 15 for biz / edu / gov)*
- **GoToMeeting:** http://www.gotomeeting.co.uk/meeting/pricing *(up to 25 in basic paid version)*

Comment: I struggle to imagine how 10 video streams would even look on a single screen...

Comment: I think that one stream is displayed at the time. Other participants are just participants...

Comment: Wouldn't any sort of streaming work in that case? (I.E. twitch or similar)? or do you still need simultaneous voice?

Comment: Think Skype / Google Hangout but without 10 users limitation... Not sure what I want really, just doing bit of research.

Comment: @user2813274 I regularly work with Citrix WebEx (not free). In full-screen mode it only shows a large video of the speaker, a tiny one of yourself embedded in a corner, and a horizontally scrollable row of 6-8 small videos of all other participants. That's 10 streams max in the window.

Answer (score 1):

FreeConferenceCall advertizes with *Try video conferencing for free with up to 1,000 participants*.

Make sure you go to the American version of the site, if your browser brings you to a localized version, scroll all the way to the bottom, and click the *FreeConferenceCall USA* link.

I have no personal experience with it, but my wife reports having used it with 25 participants.